# Problem with multillanguage url rewrite

Tags: multistore, url-rewrite, language

I have installed Magento 1.9.3 with sample data so I have category: Women clothing with url

women.html for the eng view 
femmes.html for the fr view 
frau.html for the german view

When I switch the language from the language drop down it works fine but the problem is that if I am in english homepage and access mysite.com/femmes.html it gives a 404 instead of redirecting to fr category of femmes.html

Comment: type index.php between urls. that mysite.com/index.php/femmes.html